# Does gcc upgrade requires a newer kernel too?

Tags: gcc, arm, toolchain

I use an embedded with a bit old kernel 2.6.37. 
Now we need to update rootfs with more update gcc than the one used on building the image (Instead of 4.3 need to use 5.1, because it will support c++11, which we need in application).

**When upgrading gcc, does it mean we need a newer toolchain ?**

The new toolhcian use newer kernel headers (4.0.0).

**So, When upgrading gcc, does it mean that we need a new kernel ? or does it also support the old kernel headers ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can compile software with new kernel headers and it will still run on older kernels, as long as the software does not use any new kernel features.

However, lots of programs contain constructs like this:

```
#ifdef __NR_renameat2
  int ret = syscall (__NR_renameat2,
                     oldfd, oldpath, newfd, newpath, RENAME_NOREPLACE);
#else
  int ret = renameat (oldfd, oldpath, newfd, newpath);
#endif
```

In this case, the software will use `renameat2` unconditionally after building against the 4.0 kernel headers, and it will fail when running on 2.6.37 (unless support for the `renameat2` system call has been backported).  With the older kernel headers, the `#else` part was used, but that is no longer compiled in.

The solution is to use something like this:

```
#ifdef __NR_renameat2
  int ret = syscall (__NR_renameat2,
                     oldfd, oldpath, newfd, newpath, RENAME_NOREPLACE);
#else
  int ret = -1;
  errno = ENOSYS;
#endif
  if (ret == -1 && errno == ENOSYS)
    ret = renameat (oldfd, oldpath, newfd, newpath);
```

That is, use the (slightly defective) legacy interface if you get `ENOSYS` from the kernel.  Usually, such changes are straightforward, but finding all the places which require them can be tedious.

Another area where new kernel headers will not work with older kernels involve low-level functionality, such as the data structures used by the `iptables` command line tool for the kernel.  In these areas, the promise of userspace ABI stability does not apply.  In these cases, it's not just the contents of the header files, you may also need newer versions of the userspace tools because kernel behavior has changed, and just the layout of some data structures.

(Note that GCC and most of the rest of the upstream current GNU toolchain still build with older kernel headers.  The only exception is glibc, which currently needs kernel 3.2 to build and run.  The requirement to use kernel 4.0 headers is something imposed by your GNU toolchain distribution.)

Comment: Does it mean I can never know for sure if there is something which might not work well in my new gcc , I mean if my application works today it can fail tomorrow if it will call some other syscall ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this question. Could you please rephrase? The problem I described comes from code which is not prepared to deal with the compile-time/run-time difference in kernel versions.  For your own code, I would expect you'd realize that this problem exists when you test the code for the first time in the target environment, with the intended kernel version.